.Net MAUI FindResource Method
In .Net WPF, there is a method called FindResource() for getting binded source with its key. So I need it while developing my application in .Net MAUI. Unfortunately, there is no method called FindResource or anything like it. I searched about my problem but couldn't find any answer. I actually found a post about this problem on stackoverflow but I couldn't find my answer there.
Here is my code:
private void OnMapTapped(object sender, TappedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = FindResource("MapViewModel") as MapViewModel;
    Point? p = e.GetPosition(MainMapView);
    Point pT = p.Value;
    MapPoint mp = MainMapView.ScreenToLocation(pT);
    viewModel.createPoint(mp);
}

The code that I used for declaring a resource.
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:MapViewModel x:Key="MapViewModel"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

I'm currently trying to use ArcGIS maps in my application, and in this code I'm trying to put a marker on the tapped point. However, because the FindResource method is not avalible, I can't do it. I'm following ArcGIS tutorials and MVVM pattern is used there.
This is my first time posting a question on stackoverflow, so I apologize if I did something wrong.

Just so I'm clear, are you trying to use FindResource() method to find/access your view model?

It looks like you're capturing the location where the user tapped on the map in OnMapTapped() in code behind and trying to get it to your view model. I'm also assuming the ArcGIS control doesn't offer you a Command option for the tap event. If these assumptions are true, I'd suggest you use .NET MAUI CommunityToolkit's EventToCommandBehavior to pass the data directly to your view model. Here's a link to documentation on this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior HTH.

Thanks for your help Sam. I couldn't find any alternatives for FindResource() but while thinking about this problem an idea came to my mind and I changed the structure of my code, then I could get it to work. Also I didn't need EventToCommandBehavior this time but I think that I may need it in the future. Thanks again. Edit: If you want I can share the new structure of the code.

I couldn't find any alternatives for FindResource() but with a small change I could get it to work without the need of FindResource().
How I fixed the issue:
This was the initial state of the code that I use for getting MapViewModel class in the .xaml file. My aim was to access this resource in the C# script file of the page with FindResource() method, but as I said before there was no method like it in .Net MAUI.
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:MapViewModel x:Key="MapViewModel"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

So I gave a name to this resource, with x:Name=" ". Here is the final state of the code
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <local:MapViewModel x:Key="MapViewModel" x:Name="MVM"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>

So now I can access this resource in the C# script file of the page with the name I gave it, MVM.

Even if you answer your own question, the answer should contain the solution. The fact that you modified the structure of your code and you will only share it if someone asks you will not help anyone that has the same problem.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
